# Convert excel formula into google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert a formula from excel into a formula for Google spreadsheets but it's not working. The notification I keep getting is:

> Matrix value can't be found

The formula converts Letter/lettercombinations into a average grade (number).

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C4:C11;$A$55:$A$62)*($C$55:$C$62))/COUNTA(C4:C11)
```

Where $A$55:$A$62 refers to the cells with the letters:

```
O
M
M/V
V
V/RV
RV
RV/G
G
```

and $C$55:$C$62 refers to the numbers that correspond to the letters:

```
4,5
5
5,5
6
6,5
7
7,5
8
```

C4:C11 are the cells where the teacher can choose from the different letter/lettercombinations (through validation).

Maybe there is a better way to make these calculations, so if you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the formula as a matrix formula, that is, end it with Ctrl-Shift-Return. It'll appear then as `{=SUM(COUNTIF(C4:C11;$A$55:$A$62)*($C$55:$C$62))/COUNTA(C4:C11)}`. Reason: the formula uses the values in A55...A62 and C55...C62 one after the other to form the conditional sum. To signify this, you make the formula a matrix formula.

Comment: Haha I meant shift :-)

What I mean is that when C4: C11 has more than one value the means is not only displayed in the target cell but also in the cell below the target cell (when C4: C11 has 2 values where a means is derived of). When C4: C11 has three values the means is dislayed in the target cell, but also in the cell below the target cell and the cell below that one etc.

Comment: See this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PyXfigFDgTCNY5YXm5MdJPZWPuyiaM4wF8tj53eGz38/edit?usp=sharing
In column C, D and E are the examples I was referring to.

Comment: wow, that was really helpful! the `IF` statement will always create an array of size (C4:C11) at the destination cell. Only way around IMHO: create the score on each line and sum it up, or do not exclude zeroes. Sorry, end of wits.

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(C4:C11,$G$3:$G$10) *($H$3:$H$10))/(COUNTA(C4:C11)-COUNTIF(C4:C11,0)))` should work. It will ignore the zero values in the count, not in the sum.

Comment: I got it to work with changing a few comma's:  
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(D4:D11;$A$55:$A$62) *($C$55:$C$62))/(COUNTA(D4:D11)-COUNTIF(D4:D11;0)))  

But leaving out the 'IF' argument when there's no input yet the target cell says DIV/0!. I don't want my users to see that. 
Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTA(C4:C11)=0;"";ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(C4:C11;$G$3:$G$10)*($H$3:$H$10))/(COUNTA(C4:C11)-COUNTIF(C4:C11,0))))` displays a blank if none of the source fields are filled. Sorry for the commas, seem s it's country-dependent.

Comment: SOLVED IT! I used the IFERROR function in the formula like this. 

=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(D4:D11;$A$55:$A$62)*($C$55:$C$62))/(COUNTA(D4:D11)-COUNTIF(D4:D11;0)));"")

Now it does all I want! Thank you @user1016274. You really helped me out!